# Factorial logic not giving answer

Tags: java, factorial

```
public static int fact(int x) {
    int y = x;
    for (int i = x - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        y = y * i;
    }
    return y;
}
```

I tried even the recursive method to find factorial but both the methods give answer as 0 for numbers like 3057 or any high valued number.

Comment: yeah, integer overflow. 32 bit ain't enough for *everything…*

Answer (score 2):

Try using a `long` instead of an `int`. You are probably just overrunning the integer. If that doesn't work, you'll have to switch to [`BigInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) which allow for larger sizes.

**Edit** I just tired this and it does work for smaller numbers, you are definitely overrunning the int. The BigInteger-based code below worked for an input of 3057.

```
public static BigInteger fact(int x){
    BigInteger y = BigInteger.valueOf(x);
    for(int i=x-1;i>0;i--){
        y = y.multiply(BigInteger.valueOf(i));
    }
    return y;
}
```

Or you can use the slightly less clunky [`BigDecimal`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html):

```
public static BigDecimal fact(int x){
    BigDecimal y = new BigDecimal(x);
    for(int i=x-1;i>0;i--){
        y = y.multiply(new BigDecimal(i));
    }
    return y;
}
```

Comment: Why do you think `BigDecimal` is less "clunky"? Also a "factorial" is defined for just non-negative "integers"...

Comment: I wasn't trying to provide a full implementation, just show him how BigDecimal and BigInteger work. He can write the rest of his own code. ;) As for "clunky", I think `new BigDecimal(x)` is less clunky than `BigInteger.valueOf(x)` (personal opinion).